# Rendering a .NET View From a php curl call

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling an ActionResult using curl in my php project.

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
          );

          $result = curl_exec($ch);

          print_r($result);
          curl_close($ch);
```

Everything is calling the method fine.  In my .NET project code I want to return the view on the MVC side in my .NET project but it is returning back to the php project.  Is there anyway for me to return the View and stay in my .NET project?  Thanks for any advice.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TransferView([FromBody] JObject data)       
    {
     ..... my code here

    return View(model);
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you want. Each request has a response. Do you want to get a response to other person?

Comment: What is happening is that I can make my post call from php to my .NET project.  If I do it with a 'GET' it renders my View page just fine.  With the 'POST' once it hits the 'Return View(model)', It tries to pull the page in my old URL and it is throwing the routing off and I just get a page not found.

Comment: In other words, the code you put as a sample is working fine.. the problem is when you launch a GET request from php?